# SQL Select and Delete help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax

How do you go about selecting or deleting a specific list of numbers from a table?

For example,

select * from Table where ID = 1,2,3,4,5,6

doesn't work. I would have to do where ID = 1 or ID = 2 or ID = 3 etc etc

How do you do you use a comma delineated list to select multiple values using one where clause?

Comment: By the way, awwesome user name. Don't ever lose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table where ID IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the in operator  select * from Table where ID in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
works with delete too

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
Where ID in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for dynamic query then

execute ('select * from table where ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)')

otherwise

select * from table where ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)

will do the job

Comment: This answer was quite a lot later than several others that said the exact same thing, and did not contribute with anything new. Also, the two suggested solutions are in reality the same - there is no difference whatsoever in the two sql statements...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Note that you can't insert the entire list in a parametrized query - for example, `WHERE Id IN (?)` with a parameter containing `'1,2,3,4,5,6'` will not yield the results you're after.

A nice way to avoid building your SQL string dynamically (and potentially exposing yourself to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)) is to dynamically build *the number of parameters*, and then concatenate them into your SQL.

A full example with Python and SQLite (although this method can be used in any language with any SQL database engine):

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
params = tuple(ids) # because sqlite wants the parameters in tuple format
paramstring = ', '.join(['?' for dummyp in ids])
# paramstring now contains '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?'
# - the same number of '?' as the number of ids

sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id IN (' + paramstring + ')'
# sql now contains 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = conn.execute(sql, params)

# You can now iterate through the cursor to get your data
```